# Oracle SQL Update set

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update a column with a count (+1) based on a column in the same table matching that of another, I have tried below:

```
UPDATE table1 p
   SET (p.f_dup_count)= ((p.f_dup_count) + 1)
      WHERE (SELECT a.f, 
                    p.f
               FROM table2 a,
                    table1 p
              WHERE a.f = p.f
                AND a.a_id = p.a_id)
```

This currently results in:

```
Error at Command Line:28 Column:40 Error report: SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression 00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

A very helpful solution was provided for this, as below:

UPDATE table1 p
     SET f_dup_count = (case when exists (SELECT 1
                                          FROM table2 a
                                          WHERE a.f = p.f AND
                                                a.a_id = p.a_id
                                         )
                             then f_dup_count + 1
                             else 0
                         end);

However, now I have tested it I have realised the processing time is quite High. I there a way to do this as a 'create table as select' in order to improve performance?

thanks,

Adam

Comment: The where clause needs to be 'where field/condition = field/condition'...your statement here is lacking the =...where the select statement outlined there = what (or which field in table1 equals the fields in the subquery).  If you share what you are trying to accomplish, I'm sure we can do a rewrite for you.  Side note...best not to store counts on their own in a database...better to have a statement that runs the incremental count on the fly.

Comment: I guess you want "EXITS" predicate, but error message is clear and it is easy to find the answer by error code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that the point is to update the dup count when the corresponding record is found in `table2`.

If so, you need to change the subquery to a correlated subquery, by removing the reference to `table1` in it. Then, I'm guessing that you want to check for existence of a corresponding record in `table2`, which you can do using `exists`:

```
UPDATE table1 p
     SET f_dup_count = f_dup_count + 1
     WHERE exists (SELECT 1
                   FROM table2 a
                   WHERE a.f = p.f AND
                         a.a_id = p.a_id
                  );
```

EDIT:

If you want to increment or set to 1, then you can either use two updates or move the condition into a `case` statement:

```
UPDATE table1 p
     SET f_dup_count = (case when exists (SELECT 1
                                          FROM table2 a
                                          WHERE a.f = p.f AND
                                                a.a_id = p.a_id
                                         )
                             then f_dup_count + 1
                             else 0
                         end);
```

Comment: Is it possible to add an ELSE SET f_dup_count = 0 to this statement?

Answer (score 0):

A where clause should contain a condition like `where ID = 42`.  Yours has just a value, like `where 42`.  Oracle doesn't know what to do with that value.

One way to solve your problem in Oracle is a subquery update, like:

```
UPDATE  (
        SELECT p.f_dup_count
        FROM   table2 a
        JOIN   table1 p
        ON     a.f = p.f
               AND a.a_id = p.a_id
        ) SubQueryAlias
SET     f_dup_count = f_dup_count + 1
```